# ASINetworkQueue download progress

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, asihttprequest

I need to show the download progress for ASINetworkQueue and it works fine if I add all my request to the queue and then call go method on it. but if there are some requests running in the queue already while I am adding some new operations the progress gets out of sync. Any idea why?

I'll appreciate your help.